# Architecture for audits

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am designing a database to capture audits that my company performs. I am having a bit of trouble finding an efficient way to capture all of the audit points without making 60 columns in a single table. Is there an efficient way to capture multiple data points in a single column and still be able to query without trouble.

Each audit may have anywhere from 0 to 60 unique citations. I will make a reference table to hold every regulatory citation, but how do I design the central table so that the 'citation' column can have , or , or any number of other combinations?

Comment: You break the central table into two tables, one for the basic audit details, and one for the details of each citation. Research "database normalization".

Comment: If you want it in a single table only, you may want to consider adding a column for citation with XML datatype. :-)

Comment: I have broken it out into the central table which has the audit number, the location ID, the entity ID, Date, Date of next audit, surveyor. And then a reference table for the descriptions of each type of citation. Do you suggestion I make another table with a 1 to 1 relationship with my central table that just has all the tags in it?

Comment: No, 1 to many. One audit can have many citations (or none).

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to keep auditing info in a single table.
In order to do this, I go something like this:

```
TABLE: Audit
**Id** (PK)
**EntityClass** (the Class, or type, or whatever you want to identify your entities by)
**EntityId** (the id of the entity in it's own table)
**PropertyChanged** (the name of the property of the entity that changed)
**OldValue** (the old value of the property)
**NewValue** (the revised value of the property)
**TimeStamp** (moment of the revision)
**RevisionType** (transaction type: Insert, Update, Delete)
```

This is the simplest schema, you can build on that with additional columns if you wish.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I'm assuming, since you refer to a specific number if citations, there is -- or can be -- a taxonomic table holding 60 definitions or references, one for each kind of citation.

The *Audits* table contains the relevant info about each audit. I'm guessing most of this, but note there is no reference to any citation.

```
create table Audits(
    ID          int  identity( 1, 1 ),
    Started     date,
    Completed   date,
    CustomerID  int,
    AuditorID   int,   -- More than one possible auditor? Normalize.
    VerifierID  int,
    Details     ...,
    constraint  PK_Audits primary key( ID ),
    constraint  FK_Audits_Customer( foreign key( CustomerID )
        references Customers( ID ),
    constraint  FK_Audits_Auditor( foreign key( AuditorID )
        references Auditors( ID ),
    constraint  FK_Audits_Verifier( foreign key( VerifierID )
        references Auditors( ID ),
    constraint  CK_Audits_Auditor_Verifier check( AuditorID <> VerifierID )
);
```

The *AuditCitations* table contains each citation for each audit, one entry for each citation. Note that the PK will prevent the same audit from having more than one reference to the same citation (if, of course, that is your rule).

```
create table AuditCitations(
    AuditID     int,
    CitID       int,
    Details     ...,
    constraint  FK_AuditCitations_Audit( foreign key( AuditID )
        references Audits( ID ),
    constraint  FK_AuditCitations_Citation( foreign key( CitID )
        references Citations( ID ),
    constraint  PK_AuditCitations primary key( AuditID, CitID )
);
```

A citation may well have its own auditor and verifier/checker or just about anything that applies to the particular citation. This example mainly just shows the relationship between the two tables.